# Looking for a random variable s.t. $EX^2<\infty$ but $E|X|^{2+\delta}=\infty$ for any $\delta>0$

Tags: calculus, probability

Looking for a random variable s.t.
$EX^2<\infty$ but $E|X|^{2+\delta}=\infty$ for any $\delta>0$.That is, finding a density function. I have tried a random variable whose density function is $C\cdot\frac{1}{x^2(1+x^2)} $, C is a constant. But it turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $X$ have density function of shape $\dfrac{c}{x^3\ln^2 x}$ from say $e$ on.

Comment: sorry for my poor knowledge on integral. Why $\int_e^\infty\frac{x^\delta}{xln^2x}=\infty$

Comment: In the long run it goes to $0$ more slowly than $\frac{1}{x}$, and $\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ diverges. For the more slowly part, divide by $1/x$, that is, multiply by $x$. For any positive $\delta$, $x^\delta/(\ln^2 x)$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me how do you think of this case?intuitive? Experience? I have thought it for a lot of time and get nothing.

Comment: We basically wanted something whose integral converged but more slowly than the integral of any $\frac{1}{x^{1+\delta}}$. Then $\frac{1}{x\ln^2 x}$ is standard. From series you may remember the convergence of $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}$.